# Why other devices cannot add my pass

Tags: ios6, passbook

I created a pass. I can add it to my passbook by email or app or web server. When I send it to others to test, they can open it on Mail.app and see a pass, but when they click add button, nothing adds to passbook. Why is it so ?

Comment: Usually this is due to a signing / certificate error.  If you can post a link online to the .pkpass bundle or email a copy to support@passkit[dot]com I should be able to tell you why it is not loading.

Comment: support@passkit.com ?

Comment: Yes you can use that address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your webServiceURL is HTTP, not HTTPS.

```
"webServiceURL" : "http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/"
```

The pass will load on your device because you have enabled "Allow HTTP Services" in the PassKit Testing section of the Developer menu in your device's settings.

For non-development devices (or development devices that don't have this option set), the webServiceURL has to be HTTPS.

To fix this, either change your webServiceURL to `https://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/`, or ask the people who you are sending the pass to, to Allow HTTP Services (note, they will require development devices to be able to do so).

Also note that if you change to https, your webServiceURL will probably not work because your MAMP server is not configured for SSL on port 8888.

Comment: do you know how to make SSL for MAMP ? I searched some already, but not clear and not work for me !